# Suggestions for blanking 5.25" bays

Tags: case, build

We've built a PC using used parts for my girlfriend's brother. The case we bought was slightly damaged and missing the blanking plates for the 3.5" bays. Has anyone got any suggestions on how we could make the front panel look a bit nicer and blank out these gaps?

[image: PC photo]

Thanks.

Comment: try contacting coolermaster support and see if they'll sell/give you the plates.  Otherwise you could go with something like this: https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2047675.m570.l1313&_nkw=Hard+Drive+Cage+Chassis+Rack+3x+5.25%27%27+to+5x+3.5%27%27+SATA+SAS+HDD+Tray+Case&_sacat=0

Comment: That's not a bad idea. The case is almost certainly out of production so I doubt Cooler Master will still stock spares. The hard drive caddy looks good but more money :( thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much effort you want to put into this.

You could have a custom part 3d printed to snap in there.

There are services that would print it for you at a cost, but you would still have to design it in 3d.  Or find someone to help you.

Comment: If I had a 3D printer myself I'd probably give it a go but wouldn't want to pay to have someone else to print and design it, would probably be expensive. Do you think maybe some netting or something would work? I just don't want it to look like this big gap that's currently there.

Comment: @EM-Creations  You could probably buy at sheet of plastic and cut it to size.  The bays are 5.25" wide so you want something a bit wider maybe 5.5" inches so you can trim down the edges.  The height is about 1.63" per bay so 6.52".  The actual plastic pieces aren't that complex usually the fact the pieces are slightly wider keeps them from coming out.  You could practice on a cardboard box.  Cut a sheet of cardboard that fits exactly, and then get use that to cut a sheet of plastic to that size.